# Debugging on phone

Tags: android

I have an app that I have been using for a long while now. It's open source and fell out of development. I started modifying it when it broke and it worked fine on my Epic Touch. I recently picked up the Sprint Note 2 and installed it. It forced closed on me. I decided "OK lets see whats going on and why its FCing". I ran it in an emulator 4.1.2 and it worked fine. When I tried to debug it in eclipse using the real phone my logcat showed problems and never loaded:

```
D/dalvikvm( 1032): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0

D/dalvikvm( 1032): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 153 ulemented (abstract) methods

D/AndroidRuntime( 1032): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm

W/zipro   (30332): Unable to open zip '/data/local/tmp/BalanceWidget.apk': Permission denied

D/asset   (30332): failed to open Zip archive '/data/local/tmp/BalanceWidget'

I/ApplicationPolicy( 2487): isApplicationInstallationEnabled

W/zipro   (30332): Unable to open zip '/data/local/tmp/BalanceWidget.apk': Permission denied

D/asset   (30332): failed to open Zip archive '/data/local/tmp/BalanceWidget'

D/dalvikvm( 2487): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms

W/DefContainer(30332): Failed to parse package

W/PackageManager( 2487): verifying app can be installed or not

W/DefContainer(30332): Failed to parse package

D/dalvikvm( 2487): GC_EXPLICIT freed 329K, 14% free 44856K/51591K, paused 4ms, total 96ms

D/AndroidRuntime( 1032): Shutting down VM

D/dalvikvm( 1032): GC_CONCURRENT freed 128K, 87% free 568K/4096K, paused 0ms, total 2ms

 D/jdwp    ( 1032): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
```

I tried wiping the cache, chmoding the folders, but nothing worked. I changed to a different project to see if it was that project but it did the same thing.

Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem could be and how to fix it?

**My phone:**

Rooted Stock Sprint Note 2

L900VPALJC

OS Running -  Android 4.1.1

Thanks

Comment: Are u sure you added all the necessary permissions in the manifest for the app???

Comment: Package isn't corrupt because when I hook up my Epic Touch it works fine.  The permissions from my manifest are android.permission.INTERNET and android.permission.WAKE_LOCKE

Comment: Is that a typo for the permission there actually in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: OK I found the problem. The Rooted Stock Rom was the problem. I flashed the Stock Rom and I can now access debugging through eclipse. However now I have to figure out why the app continues to force close.